# How Do I Get Visual Studio ToolBox to Auto-Populate Projects Components?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, components, toolbox

I have a Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework 2.0 project that I'm building.  It has some custom components.  These are not populated into the Toolbox.  Why not?

I once added a custom user control to the box, and it auto added all my components.  But, when I restarted Visual Studio 2008, it failed to auto populate the components that are part of the project.

Any idea on how to get them to auto populate?  Seems like a VS2008 bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an option.  Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General, AutoToolboxPopulate must be set to True.

[image]

Comment: I have that option set to true.  Yet, it doesn't auto populate the list.  It only did this once, when I added a user control, it added all the components I already had created.  But, when I restarted Visual Studio 2008, they went away.

Comment: I dunno, time to reset it.  Right-click + Reset.  Rebuild your project.

Comment: Well, a rebuild all added them in, so I'll mark this as answered.  Still seems kind of buggy.  Thanks for your help.